# Draw rectangle with Mouse on HTML5 Video using javascript

Tags: html5-canvas

I have embedded a Video in HTML5 page over a Canvas.
I want to draw a rectangle with mouse events on the Video and rectangle should not be erased.

Please help me how to do this ..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Canvas Element just on top of your Video-Canvas. and Handle your mouse events for that new canvas element. and Make sure that you do not set the background property for your new canvas, this will make it transparent and the Video-Canvas elements content will be visible. Let me know if you do not get it.

Comment: I didn't get it. I want to do it on videojs player. Is there anything available?

Comment: You can add a transparent HTML5 canvas element covering your video view.Also you would need to handle mouse event drag etc to draw on it.